# low conductivity material compatible with MRI

Tags: electrical-resistance

I am looking for a conductor with low electrical conductivity (around 1 S/m) which can be moulded into a mask.

Comment: Be more specific.

Comment: edited the question, please check...

Comment: Ok. I think you shouldn't remove the first info about the MRI. Detail the problem more, also this MRI thing what you removed. If you ask a question, there are 3 things needed: 1) what are you looking for 2) what you found 3) why is it not enough. Reopening your question requires 5 votes and my is only 1 from them. To get the other votes (3 is needed now), you need to formulate 1), 2) and 3) in a clear, round text.